# Pandas fill column with row value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that look like this.

```
key            values
Interface       InterfaceA
State           Up
Line Status     Up
ID              9000
Interface       InterfaceB
State           Down
Line Status     Down
ID              9001
```

And I would like to transform it to become like this

```
Interface        State        Line Status       ID
InterfaceA        Up             Up             9000
InterfaceB        Down           Down           9001
```

I've try to use loc to insert the column by column, but when it reaches 2nd columns

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

the above error appears.

```
final_df['Interface'] = commands_df.loc[commands_df['key'].str.contains('Interface'), 'values']
final_df['State'] = commands_df.loc[commands_df['key'].str.contains('State'), 'values'] <-- Error starts here

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Comment: Transpose will transpose every row instead of categories them together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `set_index` with `cumcount` and `unstack`

```
df_final = df.set_index([df.groupby('key').cumcount(),'key'])['values'].unstack()

Out[423]:
key    ID   Interface Line-Status State
0    9000  InterfaceA          Up    Up
1    9001  InterfaceB        Down  Down
```

Another method is using `pd.crosstab`

```
df_final = pd.crosstab(df.groupby('key')['values'].cumcount(), 
                       df['key'], 
                       df['values'], aggfunc='first')

Out[424]:
key      ID   Interface Line-Status State
row_0
0      9000  InterfaceA          Up    Up
1      9001  InterfaceB        Down  Down
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.assign(Interface=df[df['key'] == 'Interface']['values']).ffill()
print(df.pivot(index='Interface', columns='key', values='values').drop(columns='Interface'))
```

Prints:

```
key           ID Line Status State
Interface                         
InterfaceA  9000          Up    Up
InterfaceB  9001        Down  Down
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution-

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=['InterfaceA', 'Up', 'Up', 9000, 'InterfaceB', 'Down', 'Down', 9001],
                  index=['Interface', 'State', 'Line Status', 'ID', 'Interface', 'State', 'Line Status', 'ID'])

df = df.T
print(df.groupby(df.columns.values, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).sum().apply(pd.Series).T)
```

```
     ID   Interface Line Status State
0  9000  InterfaceA          Up    Up
1  9001  InterfaceB        Down  Down
```

credits to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50083006/10733051)