# Pandas dataframe merge duplicate columns one below another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data such as below:

| x | x | y | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

I want to merge duplicate columns one below another row wise like this

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

Is there a way I can achieve this in pandas dataframe?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the number of rows for each column name will be equal in the end? So is N(x1) + N(x2) + N(xn) == N(y1) + N(y2)..

Comment: Beny has the perfect answer for this. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50083006/6660373.  `df.groupby(df.columns.values, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).sum().apply(pd.Series).T
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpivot multiple columns with same name in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082846/unpivot-multiple-columns-with-same-name-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Pygirl correct me if I am wrong, but that does not work, if the pivoted data is read from file right?

Comment: @FloLie: I guess yes it won;t work. It's only work when you are having a dataframe in this form.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is the result of a groupby / pivot on an existing dataframe @Pygirl comment is corrent and  I refer to her/his link as [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082846/unpivot-multiple-columns-with-same-name-in-pandas-dataframe)

However it does not work if the data is to be read from file, as pandas does not allow for duplicate named columns and modifies them as `name, name.1, name.n`.

My answer refers to that case with dummy input `test_import`

```
X,X,Y
1,2,1
3,4,2
5,6,3
```

It basically finds all associated columns x -> (X, X.1,..) Creates a dict with unique keys, and concatinates the associated columns together.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv("test_import", sep=",")
pattern = r"([^\.]*)\.{0,1}.*"
unique_header = set(re.match(pattern, i).groups()[0] for i in df.columns)
result = dict()

for header in unique_header:
    result[header] = []
    for column in df.columns:
        if column[:len(header)] == header:
            result[header].append(df[column])
    result[header] = pd.concat(result[header])
    
final = pd.DataFrame()
for key, value in result.items():
    final[key] = value

print(final)
```

I do admit, that this is not a sexy answer and I am happy for input for a leaner way, but I didn't come up with one.

```
   X  Y
0  1  1
1  3  2
2  5  3
0  2  1
1  4  2
2  6  3
```