# Column Pair-wise aggregation and reorganization in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, aggregate, melt

I am importing a csv file into a pandas dataframe such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {0: {0: 'ID', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5'}, 1: {0: 'Net Cost', 1: '30', 2: '40', 3: '50', 4: '35', 5: '45'}, 2: {0: 'Charge Description', 1: 'Surcharge A', 2: 'Discount X', 3: 'Discount X', 4: 'Discount X', 5: 'Surcharge A'}, 3: {0: 'Charge Amount', 1: '9.5', 2: '-12.5', 3: '-11.5', 4: '-5.5', 5: '9.5'}, 4: {0: 'Charge Description', 1: 'Discount X', 2: '', 3: '', 4: 'Surcharge B', 5: 'Discount X'}, 5: {0: 'Charge Amount', 1: '-11.5', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '3.5', 5: '-10.5'}, 6: {0: 'Charge Description', 1: 'Discount Y', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: 'Surcharge B'}, 7: {0: 'Charge Amount', 1: '-3.25', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '4.5'}, 8: {0: 'Charge Description', 1: 'Surcharge B', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: ''}, 9: {0: 'Charge Amount', 1: '2.5', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: ''}} )
```

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | Net Cost | Charge Description | Charge Amount | Charge Description | Charge Amount | Charge Description | Charge Amount | Charge Description | Charge Amount |
| 1 | 30 | Surcharge A | 9.5 | Discount X | -11.5 | Discount Y | -3.25 | Surcharge B | 2.5 |
| 2 | 40 | Discount X | -12.5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 50 | Discount X | -11.5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 35 | Discount X | -5.5 | Surcharge B | 3.5 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 45 | Surcharge A | 9.5 | Discount X | -10.5 | Surcharge B | 4.5 |  |  |

The first row are the headers with column names Charge Description and Charge Amount forming pairs and appearing multiple times.

Desired output is a df with a unique column for each description, with the reorganized columns sorted alphabetically and NaNs showing as 0:

| ID | Net Cost | Surcharge A | Surcharge B | Discount X | Discount Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 9.5 | 2.5 | -11.5 | -3.25 |
| 2 | 40 | 0 | 0 | -12.5 | 0 |
| 3 | 50 | 0 | 0 | -11.5 | 0 |
| 4 | 35 | 0 | 3.5 | -5.5 | 0 |
| 5 | 45 | 9.5 | 4.5 | -10.5 | 0 |

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082846/unpivot-multiple-columns-with-same-name-in-pandas-dataframe) looks like a good starting point but then I need a column for each Charge Description and only a single row per ID.

Comment: Are the column headers REALLY supposed to be the first row of your dataframe? Or is that a "bug" in your code initialising the example dataframe? (If you read it from a csv file you should tell pandas to use the first row as headers...)

Comment: @MatBailie I initially did that but then python will change the column names to Charge Description.1, Charge Description.2, Charge Description.3 etc. Just wanted to show that they're actually all named the same.

Comment: Care to share the source file? Might be easier to reshape if read in as a Multiindex

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gFw1pD9ivlvyovlg5wY2ZIn_Rvk2f_sc/view?usp=sharing @sammywemmy

Comment: You state you want the columns sorted alphabetically, yet you have columns starting with `S` coming before columns starting with `D`?

Answer (score 2):

I used the file you shared, and edited the columns with the initial dataframe `df` shared (Pandas automatically adds suffixes to columns to make them unique) to keep the non uniqueness:

```py
invoice = pd.read_csv('Downloads/Example Invoice.csv')
invoice.columns = ['ID', 'Net Cost', 'Charge Description', 'Charge Amount',
                   'Charge Description', 'Charge Amount', 
                   'Charge Description', 'Charge Amount', 
                   'Charge Description', 'Charge Amount']
print(invoice)
   ID  Net Cost Charge Description  Charge Amount  ... Charge Description  Charge Amount Charge Description  Charge Amount
0   1        30        Surcharge A            9.5  ...         Discount Y          -3.25        Surcharge B            2.5
1   2        40         Discount X          -12.5  ...                NaN            NaN                NaN            NaN
2   3        50         Discount X          -11.5  ...                NaN            NaN                NaN            NaN
3   4        35         Discount X           -5.5  ...                NaN            NaN                NaN            NaN
4   5        45        Surcharge A            9.5  ...        Surcharge B           4.50                NaN            NaN
```

First step is to transform to long form with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) - in this case we take advantage of the fact that `charge description` is followed by `charge amount` - we can safely pair them and reshape into two columns. After that is done, we flip back to wide form - getting `Surcharge` and `Discount` values as headers. Thankfully, the index is unique, so a pivot works without extras. I used [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) here, primarily for convenience - the same can be achieved with `pivot`, with just a few cleanup steps - under the hood [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) uses `pd.pivot`.

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

index = ['ID', 'Net Cost']
arr = ['Charge Description', 'Charge Amount']
(invoice
.pivot_longer(
    index = index, 
    names_to = arr, 
    names_pattern = arr, 
    dropna=True)
.pivot_wider(
    index=index,
    names_from='Charge Description', 
    values_from='Charge Amount')
.fillna(0)
)

   ID  Net Cost  Discount X  Discount Y  Surcharge A  Surcharge B
0   1        30       -11.5       -3.25          9.5          2.5
1   2        40       -12.5        0.00          0.0          0.0
2   3        50       -11.5        0.00          0.0          0.0
3   4        35        -5.5        0.00          0.0          3.5
4   5        45       -10.5        0.00          9.5          4.5
```

Another option - since the data is fairly consistent with the ordering, you can dump down into numpy, reshape into a two column array, keep track of the `ID` and `Net Cost` columns (ensure they are correctly paired), and then pivot to get your final data:

```py
index = ['ID', 'Net Cost']
arr = ['Charge Description', 'Charge Amount']
invoice = invoice.set_index(index)
out = invoice.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 2)
out = pd.DataFrame(out, columns = arr)
# reshape above is in order `C` - default
# so we can safely repeat the index
# with a value of 4
# which is what you get -> 
# invoice.columns.size // 2
# to correctly pair the index with the new dataframe
out.index = invoice.index.repeat(invoice.columns.size//2)
# get rid of nulls, and flip to wide form
(out
.dropna(how='all')
.set_index('Charge Description', append=True)
.squeeze()
.unstack('Charge Description', fill_value=0)
.rename_axis(columns = None)
.reset_index()
)

   ID  Net Cost Discount X Discount Y Surcharge A Surcharge B
0   1        30      -11.5      -3.25         9.5         2.5
1   2        40      -12.5          0           0           0
2   3        50      -11.5          0           0           0
3   4        35       -5.5          0           0         3.5
4   5        45      -10.5          0         9.5         4.5
```

You can convert the data dtypes for `Discount` to numeric

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten your dataframe first with `melt` then reshape with `pivot_table` after cleaning it up:

```
# 1st pass
out = (pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[1:].values, columns=df.iloc[0].tolist())
         .melt(['ID', 'Net Cost'], ignore_index=False))

m = out['variable'] == 'Charge Description'

# 2nd pass
out = (pd.concat([out[m].reset_index(drop=True).add_prefix('_'),
                  out[~m].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
         .query("_value != ''")
         .pivot_table(index=['ID', 'Net Cost'], columns='_value',
                      values='value', aggfunc='first')
         .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index().fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  ID Net Cost Discount X Discount Y Surcharge A Surcharge B
0  1       30      -11.5      -3.25         9.5         2.5
1  2       40      -12.5          0           0           0
2  3       50      -11.5          0           0           0
3  4       35       -5.5          0           0         3.5
4  5       45      -10.5          0         9.5         4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_table` after concatenating pair-wise:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {0: {0: 'ID', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5'}, 1: {0: 'Net Cost', 1: '30', 2: '40', 3: '50', 4: '35', 5: '45'}, 2: {0: 'Charge Description', 1: 'Surcharge A', 2: 'Discount X', 3: 'Discount X', 4: 'Discount X', 5: 'Surcharge A'}, 3: {0: 'Charge Amount', 1: '9.5', 2: '-12.5', 3: '-11.5', 4: '-5.5', 5: '9.5'}, 4: {0: 'Charge Description', 1: 'Discount X', 2: '', 3: '', 4: 'Surcharge B', 5: 'Discount X'}, 5: {0: 'Charge Amount', 1: '-11.5', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '3.5', 5: '-10.5'}, 6: {0: 'Charge Description', 1: 'Discount Y', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: 'Surcharge B'}, 7: {0: 'Charge Amount', 1: '-3.25', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '4.5'}, 8: {0: 'Charge Description', 1: 'Surcharge B', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: ''}, 9: {0: 'Charge Amount', 1: '2.5', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: ''}})

# setting first row as header
df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]
df.drop(index=0, inplace=True)

df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, [0,1,i,i+1]] for i in range(2, len(df.columns), 2)]).replace('', 0)

print(df[df['Charge Description']!=0]
    .pivot_table(columns='Charge Description', values='Charge Amount', index=['ID', 'Net Cost'])
    .fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
Charge Description  Discount X  Discount Y  Surcharge A  Surcharge B
ID Net Cost                                                         
1  30                    -11.5       -3.25          9.5          2.5
2  40                    -12.5        0.00          0.0          0.0
3  50                    -11.5        0.00          0.0          0.0
4  35                     -5.5        0.00          0.0          3.5
5  45                    -10.5        0.00          9.5          4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `melt` to stack the identically named columns, then pivot to create the outcome you want.

```
# Ensure the first line is now the column names, and then delete the first line.
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]

# Create two melted df's, and join them on index.
df1 = df.melt(['ID', 'Net Cost'], ['Charge Description']).sort_values(by='ID').reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df.melt(['ID', 'Net Cost'], ['Charge Amount']).sort_values(by='ID').reset_index(drop=True)
df1['Charge Amount'] = df2['value']

# Clean up a little, rename the added 'value' column from df1. 
df1 = df1.drop(columns=[0]).rename(columns={'value': 'Charge Description'})
df1 = df1.dropna()
# Pivot the data.
df1 = df1.pivot(index=['ID', 'Net Cost'], columns='Charge Description', values='Charge Amount')
```

Result of df1:

```
Charge Description Discount X Discount Y Surcharge A Surcharge B
ID Net Cost                                                     
1  30                   -11.5      -3.25         9.5         2.5
2  40                   -12.5        NaN         NaN         NaN
3  50                   -11.5        NaN         NaN         NaN
4  35                    -5.5        NaN         NaN         3.5
5  45                   -10.5        NaN         9.5         4.5`
```

Comment: I believe that `dropna()` won't work here as the values are `''` rather than `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to read the data out in to a list of dictionaries representing each Row (making both the keys and values from the data values), then form a new dataframe from that.

For your example, that would make...

```
[
  {
    'ID': '1',
    'Net Cost': '30',
    'Discount X': '-11.5',
    'Discount Y': '-3.25',
    'Surcharge A': '9.5',
    'Surcharge B': '2.5',
  },
  {
    'ID': '2',
    'Net Cost': '40',
    'Discount X': '-12.5',
  },
  {
    'ID': '3',
    'Net Cost': '50',
    'Discount X': '-11.5',
  },
  {
    'ID': '4',
    'Net Cost': '35',
    'Discount X': '-5.5',
    'Surcharge B': '3.5',
  },
  {
    'ID': '5',
    'Net Cost': '45',
    'Discount X': '-10.5',
    'Surcharge A': '9.5',
    'Surcharge B': '4.5',
  },
]
```

***For the SMALL sample dataset***, using comprehensions appears to be quite quick for that...

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

rows = [
  {
    name: value
      for name, value in chain(
        [
          ("ID", row[0]),
          ("Net Cost", row[1]),
        ],
        zip(row[2::2], row[3::2]) # pairs of columns: (2,3), (4,5), etc
      )
      if name
  }
  for ix, row in df.iloc[1:].iterrows() # Skips the row with the column headers
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rows).fillna(0)
```

Demo *(including timings of this and three other answers)*:

- https://trinket.io/python3/555f860855

***EDIT:***

To sort the column names, add the following...

```
df2 = df2[['ID', 'Net Cost', *sorted(df2.columns[2:])]]
```